# Obtaining a list of ordered integers from a list of "pairs" in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list

Hello I am currently working with a large set of data which contains an even amount of integers, all of which have a matching value. I am trying to create a list which is made up of "one of a pair" in Python.I am able to have multiple pairs of the same value, thus simply using the `set` function does not work. For example, if I have a list:

```
List = [10, 10, 11, 20, 15, 20, 15, 11, 10, 10]
```

In this example, indices `0` and `1` would be a pair, then `2` and `7`, `3` and `5`, `4` and `6`, `8` and `9`.

I want to extract from that list the values that make up each pair and create a new list with said values to produce something such as:

```
newList = [10, 11, 20, 15, 10]
```

Using the set function makes it such that only one element from the entire set of data is put into the list, where I need half of the total data from `List`. For situations where I have more than one pair of the same value, it would look something such as:

```
List = [10, 10, 11, 10, 11, 10]
```

Would need to produce a list such as:

```
newList = [10, 11, 10]
```

Any insight would be great as I am new to Python and there are a lot of functions I may not be aware of.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the "pair" thing here. Your desired output could simply be achieved by *de-duplicating* the entire list (e.g. `set(List)`), without needing to care much about "pairs"…

Comment: what should be the output for `[1, 1, 1]`? does your input contain pairs only? the problem seems not well defined to me...

Comment: @deceze The problem with de-duplicating the entire list is that if I have two pairs, e.g. [10, 10, 10, 10], I would need a new list that has two elements, one for each pair. I also need to keep the unsorted order List is formatted in.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist There will never be that situation for me, List always has an even amount of each value.

Comment: It's still very unclear how you define "pair" here.

Comment: @deceze A pair would mean two corresponding items, similar in form or function and matched or associated. For this case, two matching integers in a list.

Comment: So, in your new example, indices `0` and `1` would be a pair, then `2` and `7`, `3` and `5`, `4` and `6`, `8` and `9`?

Comment: @deceze Yes exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
new_list = set(list)
```

This should return your desired output.

Comment: This method does not seem to produce the desired result due to having more than one pair of each. For example, I might have situations where there are four of the same integer, or two pairs. In this situation, I would want newList to contain two elements, one from each pair.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly, you don't want to have any duplicated value, want to retain a list with unique values from a particular list.

If I'm right, a simple way to do so would be:

```
List = [10, 10, 11, 11, 15, 20, 15, 20]
newList = []
for x in List:
    if x not in newList:
        newList.append(x)

print(newList)
```

A python-like way to do so would be:

```
newList = set(List)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slight variation on one of @Alain T's answer:

```
 [i for s in [set()] for i in List if (s.remove(i) if i in s else (not s.add(i)))]
```

NB: the following was my answer before you add the ordering requirement

```
sorted(List)[::2]
```

This sorts the input `List` and then take only one value out of each two consecutive.

Comment: This will not preserve the original order as illustrated in the OP's second example.

Comment: This constraint was not there when I answered... I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

As a general approach, this'll do:

```
l = [10, 10, 11, 20, 15, 20, 15, 11, 10, 10]
i = 0
while i < len(l):
    del l[l.index(l[i], i + 1)]
    i += 1
```

It iterates through the list one by one, finding the index of the *next* occurrence of the current value, and deletes it, shortening the list. This can probably be dressed up in various ways, but is a simple algorithm. Should a number *not* have a matching pair, this will raise a `ValueError`.

Comment: The issue is, would this not delete a second identical pair?

Comment: It only deletes the second item of each pair. `list.index` only finds the first subsequent occurrence, and it's only executed once for each pair.

Answer (score 0):

The following code reates a new list of half the number of items occuring in the input list. The order is in the order of first occurrence in the input list.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = [10, 10, 11, 20, 15, 20, 15, 11, 10, 10]
>>> c = Counter(d)
>>> c
Counter({10: 4, 11: 2, 20: 2, 15: 2})
>>> answer  = sum([[key] * (val // 2) for key, val in c.items()], [])
>>> answer
[10, 10, 11, 20, 15]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to preserve the order of the first occurrence of each pair, you could use a set with an XOR operation on values to alternate between first and second occurrences.

```
List = [10, 10, 11, 20, 15, 20, 15, 11, 10, 10]

paired = [ i for pairs in [set()] for i in List if pairs.symmetric_difference_update({i}) or i in pairs]
print(p)
# [10, 11, 20, 15, 10]
```

You could also do this with the accumulate function from itertools:

```
from itertools import accumulate
paired = [a for a,b in zip(List,accumulate(({n} for n in List),set.__xor__)) if a in b]
print(paired)
# [10, 11, 20, 15, 10]
```

Or use a bitmap instead of a set (if your values are relatively small positive integers (e.g. between 0 and 64):

```
paired = [ n for n,m in zip(List,accumulate((1<<n for n in List),int.__xor__)) if (1<<n)&m ]
print(paired)
# [10, 11, 20, 15, 10]
```

Or you could use a Counter from collections

```
from collections import Counter
paired = [ i for c in [Counter(List)] for i in List if c.update({i:-1}) or c[i]&1 ]
print(paired)
# [10, 11, 20, 15, 10]
```

And , if you're not too worried about efficiency, a double sort with a 2 step striding could do it:

```
paired = [List[i] for i,_ in sorted(sorted(enumerate(List),key=lambda n:n[1])[::2])]
print(paired)
# [10, 11, 20, 15, 10]
```